# What does "warning: hostname domain.com does not resolve to address" actually mean?

Tags: postfix

Variations of this warning show up many times in the Postfix logs:

```
warning: hostname 107-174-39-133-host.colocrossing.com does not resolve
     to address 107.174.39.133: Name or service not known
```

I'd like to know what this warning actually means.

Specifically, is it a forward or reverse DNS check that's failing? Is it using A, MX or PTR records? Is the failure caused by the remote mail server using cloudflare.com? Or is Postfix catching a spammer impersonating a server that isn't theirs?

Here's a live example of `dig` queries:

```
dig -x 107.174.39.133

;; ANSWER SECTION:
133.39.174.107.in-addr.arpa. 300 IN PTR 107-174-39-133-host.colocrossing.com.


dig 107-174-39-133-host.colocrossing.com

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
colocrossing.com.   355 IN  SOA brad.ns.cloudflare.com. dns.cloudflare.com. 2324254619 10000 2400 604800 1800
```

The reverse lookup PTR matches the domain to the IP address, but the forward lookup doesn't return an IP address.

I'd like to know if this is spam or a Postfix misconfiguration?

**Please note**: I already have `smtp_host_lookup = native` set, and the server's real IP address set in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
xx.xx.xx.xx     domain.com
xx:xx::xx:xx:xx:xx   domain.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using forward-confirmed reverse DNS (FCrDNS) and

```
warning: hostname 107-174-39-133-host.colocrossing.com does not resolve
     to address 107.174.39.133: Name or service not known
```

is telling you that the hostname `107-174-39-133-host.colocrossing.com` from PTR lookup has no A record at all. The hostname needs to resolve to the original IP address via its A record.

> I'd like to know if this is spam or a Postfix misconfiguration?

This is what seems to be configured. Checking a PTR record alone allows any host with a faked reverse DNS name to circumvent various security settings on your server. You can require FCrDNS (which is a good idea generally) and either reject misconfigured hosts outright (with possible, manual whitelisting), or you accept the connection and deal with potential spam later.

Comment: So this is likely spam then? I was concerned that the `cloudflare.com` setup may cause the DNS check to fail and create a false-positive.

Comment: We can't tell you that. However, 107.174.39.133 is listed on spamhaus and sorbs DNSBLs.